# Create two buttons next to each other in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, window

I'd like to create two buttons in the bottom of the window, one on the far left and the other one on the right. I'm using BorderPane and AnchorPane. When running only one button is displayed, because I call the method `BorderPane.setBottom()`two times, the first call is executed, the second one is not atleast not in a way I'd like it to. Is there a way to do this using BorderPane? I've only seen help for other versions.

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
AddArea addArea = new AddArea();
DeleteArea deleteArea = new DeleteArea();
root.setBottom(deleteArea.getPane());
root.setBottom(addArea.getPane());

public class AddArea {
    private final AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    private final Button addButton = new Button("Add");

    public AddArea() {
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(addButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(addButton, 10.0);

        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(addButton);
    }

    public Node getPane() {
        return anchorPane;
    }
}

public class DeleteArea {
    private final AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    private final Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");

    public DeleteArea() {
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(deleteButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(deleteButton, 10.0);

        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(deleteButton);
    }
    public Node getPane() {
        return anchorPane;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use an `HBox`. Add a `Button`. Add a `Pane`. Add a `Button`. Set the `Pane` to `HBox.AlwaysGrow`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving 2 elements seperate alignments in a single hbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562409/giving-2-elements-seperate-alignments-in-a-single-hbox)

Comment: @Sedrick I was rather looking for an answer on how to do this using only BorderPane and AnchorPane.

Comment: Good luck with that!